# Can I use Modernizr to detect ES6 module support?

Tags: modernizr, es6-modules

I've browsed the [Modernizr docs](https://modernizr.com/docs#features) for a property that tells whether Ecmascript 6' support for module scripts is available in the client or not, as Firefox currently doesn't. I found none. Am I missing something obvious or could I deduce this from a property that regards something else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

but that's not available as built-in test in Modernizr as far as I know (Modernizr 3.5.0). So, you could use:

```
Modernizr.addTest('es6module', function(){
   return 'noModule' in document.createElement('script')
});
```

In order for `Modernizr.addTest` to work, of course, you have to add `addTest` option to your build.

Testing `script nomodule` feature *should be* fine. That means, false positives and negatives are imaginable to happen.